# Django: How can i pass user input value from models.py to other file(ex entity_exctraction.py)

Tags: python, json, django, sqlite, django-rest-framework

I am new to Django so please guide if i am going on wrong way.

**Problem Defination:**
To take user input AS string and perform various manipulations on the input and save the modified value in the database.I also want to show this modified input as a json response.

For temporary purpose i have created 4 fields namely ticker,open,close,volume.I want to transfer the open value from models.py to entity_exctraction.py file and multiply by 2 and save the updated value to the database.

I tried to write the same logic in the models.py (commented part) and its working fine.but what i want is to write all business logic in some different file.

***Models.py***

```
from django.db import models
from .entity_exctraction import Exctraction

class Stock(models.Model):

    ticker = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    open = models.FloatField()
    close = models.FloatField()
    volume= models.IntegerField()
    open_val = Exctraction.update(open)

    #def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None,
    #    update_fields=None):
    #   print(self.open)
    #   self.open = self.open * 2
    #   super(Stock, self).save()
def __str__(self):
    return self.ticker
```

***entity_exctraction.py***

```
from django.db import models


class Exctraction():

    def update(val):
        val = val * 2.0
        return val
```

***serializers.py***

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from .models import Stock

class StockSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Stock
        print(type(model))
        #model.open=model.open*2
        #fields = ('ticker', 'volume')
        fields = '__all__'
```

[image: overview of structure]

Comment: I can't see why you need an actual Extraction class. Why not just functions in extraction.py?

Comment: @DanielRoseman  Actually i want to perform several task (related to natural language processing) on the one user input string. So i want whole bunch of code in separate python file.

Comment: @DanielRoseman i also tried writing direct function but now it is giving me error unsupported operant type.

As i am passing "open" which is having FloatField type and multiplaying with 2.It is not passing original value to other file.